# Why is my rep lower than it should be?

Tags: support, reputation

Why do I only have 31 in reputation when I got a total of five upvotes?

On my user page it says I answered two questions with scores of 2 and 3. I think you get 10 rep for upvotes on answers. One answer could be that I do not get rep from the answer scoring 2 ups because that questions has got so many answers already. But it says "21 answers" and I think the limit is 30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[One of your answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/117440/25936), the one with the 2 upvotes, is on a question that was made [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) before you answered (or before you got any upvotes). You don't earn or lose rep for those - but you can still earn badges.

Further investigating, the question was made community wiki on [Nov 1 at 23:06](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/117243/revisions), and you answered on Nov 2 at 10:21, so it was automatically turned to community wiki, as shown in the [revision history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/117440/revisions).

> But it says "21 answers" and I think the limit is 30.

The limit [here is 15](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/the-15-answer-cw-conversion-really-sucks). 30 is the limit at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and can be different at different sites.

Comment: Updated the link to "revision history" to point at the history of your answer, it was incorrectly pointed to the history of the question - which the link at "Nov 1 at 23:06" is meant for.

Comment: Ah, now I found the revision history on each post. ^^